# How to map addresses with parameters in proxy-config file using Angular?

Tags: angular, proxy, routes, angular-cli

I am currently in the development phase of my application and am using a proxy-config.json file to map my API calls to the backend server running on a different port. At the moment, I have to specify each API call in my proxy-config file before using it. I have came across a problem when having to call an address with a parameter. I am not sure how I can implement this using the proxy-config file. I have something like this that is currently working correctly.

```
        "/migrations": {
         "target": "http://localhost:9090",
         "secure": false,
         "changeOrigin": true,
         "logLevel": "debug",
         "pathRewrite": {
         "^/migrations": "/service/api/migrations/"
         }
```

And I want to implement something like this:

```
        "/migrations/{id}": {
         "target": "http://localhost:9090",
         "secure": false,
         "changeOrigin": true,
         "logLevel": "debug",
         "pathRewrite": {
         "^/migrations/{id}": "/service/api/migrations/{id}/"
         }
```

Is something like this possible? Or do I have to resort to something else? Please help. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Actually,

I was actually able to fix my problem a different way.
I was specifying every api call in my proxy-config.json file.
This isn't the correct way to do it. Instead I needed to do something like this:

```
      "/service/api/*": {
      "target": "http://localhost:9090",
      "secure": false,
      "logLevel": "debug"
      }
      }
```

In this way, any url that begins with '/service/api/' will automatically redirect to desired host address. So now if I do a GET at '/service/api/migrations/id' it will point to 'localhost:9090/app/api/migrations/id'.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing "/migrations/*" instead of "/migrations/{id}"

Comment: And in the pathRewrite don't include the {id} for the part that you're rewriting. Just rewrite "^/migrations/" : "/service/api/migrations/"